# Couldn't find any package by glob 'Python-3.7.0'

Tags: 16.04, apt, software-installation, python3

I got a `E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'Python-3.7.0'` error message when trying to install Python 3.7 in Ubuntu 16.04

```
ns3@ns3-virtual-machine:~$ sudo apt install Python-3.7.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done 
E: Unable to locate package Python-3.7.0
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'Python-3.7.0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'Python-3.7.0'
```

```
ns3@ns3-virtual-machine:~$ sudo apt install Python-3.7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package Python-3.7
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'Python-3.7'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'Python-3.7'
ns3@ns3-virtual-machine:~$ sudo apt install python3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3 is already the newest version (3.5.1-3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
ns3@ns3-virtual-machine:~$ python --version
Python 2.7.12
ns3@ns3-virtual-machine:~$ apt policy python-3.7
N: Unable to locate package python-3.7
N: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python-3.7'
N: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python-3.7
ns3@ns3-virtual-machine:~$
```

Comment: Please don't include pictures of text, we cannot copy/paste from pictures - so include text.  I can't check as I can't copy - but `python` should be all lower case  (*note: as I couldn't copy/paste due to picture - I didn't look for other errors*)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Ubuntu 16.04 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa   
sudo apt-get update   
sudo apt install python3.7
```

Alternatively you can also install Python3.8 in Ubuntu 16.04 with the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa   
sudo apt-get update   
sudo apt install python3.8
```

And similarly you can install Python3.9 from ppa:deadsnakes/ppa in Ubuntu 18.04, 20.04 and 22.04.

To show the Python 3.7 version run the following command:

```
python3.7 -V
```

To start the Python 3.7 interpreter run the following command:

```
python3.7
```

To exit the Python 3.x interpreter run the following command:

```
exit
```

Comment: After having done that, still I am getting `E: Unable to locate package python3.7
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.7'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.7'
`

Comment: @Gulzar The reason for the error message is that 16.04 is end of life. For the solution to this error message please read the answers to [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/q/91815/).

Comment: Still geting E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.7'